# correct format for fetching data from a websites API

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am attempting to fetch data from a websites API into my react/leaflet application. So far I have the data returning in the console:

```react
    fetch('https://thesession.org/members/nearby?latlon=53,-6&radius=1000&format=json&perpage=50')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(members => {
            console.log(members);
            this.setState({
              Nearbymems : members.Nearbymems
            });
          });
```

I then attempt to display the members as markers on my map using the following :

```react
  {this.state.NearbyMems.map(members => (
           <Marker
                   position={[members.location.latitude, members.location.longitude]}
                   icon={myIcon3} >
              <Popup>
              <em>{members.name}, </em>
                  {members.bio} {'\n'}

                   <PopupModal initialModalState={true}/>
              </Popup>
           </Marker>
         ))}
```

While this is producing no errors and my app is compiling and running without errors, no markers are being displayed. 
This is a sample of what the JSON data being returned is displayed like:

```
{
"latlon": "53,-6",
"radius": "1000",
"format": "json",
"perpage": "50",
"pages": 108,
"page": 1,
"total": 5391,
"members": [
    {
        "id": 85639,
        "name": "____",
        "url": "https://thesession.org/members/85639",
        "location": {
            "latitude": "____",
            "longitude": "_____"
        },
        "date": "",
        "bio": ""
    },
```

edit:

Code for myIcon3:

```
var myIcon3 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/pengbrew_160x160.png',
    iconSize: [25, 51],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 51],
    popupAnchor: [0, -51],
});
```

output of fetch:

```
Object
  format: "json"
  latlon: "53,-6"
  members: (50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
  {…}, {…}, {…},{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}
  {…}, {…},{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
  {…}, {…},{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  page:   1
  pages:  108
  perpage: "50"
  radius:  "1000"
  total :   5391
  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is the code for `myIcon3 `?

Comment: Hello sir, I will update the question to include the code to myIcon3. Since posting this question I have declared the state to be `Nearbymems : [ ], ` and since it has broken.

Comment: Your icon code seems correct. Not sure what causes the problem without seeing a working example

Comment: members.Nearbymems isn't in the JSON response you posted

Comment: @matt so would I be right in saying that for the data to not cause an error, Id have to declare say `Nearbymems : members.name` ??

Comment: @kboul I am in the process of trying to get a working example up and running.

Comment: Can you show what is logged by the console.log in the fetch?

Comment: @Matt I've posted the output above. thanks.

Comment: Thanks, there isn't a `nearbyMems` property so you are setting your state to undefined.

Comment: @Matt would I be correct in saying that I must then define what is outputted in my fetch, eg:  `this.setState({
              members: {
                id: members.id,
                name: members.name,
                url: members.url,
                location: {
               latitude: members.latitude,
               longitude: members.longitude,
             },
         date: members.date,
         bio: members.bio
     },`

Comment: No, if what you're calling `nearbyMems` is actually `members` then just `setState({ nearbyMems: members.members })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my own question. I was using an IP finder called *IPAPI* which required me to format its lat/lng with:

```
lng: location.longitude
lat: location.latitude
```

This feature was to catch users IPs if they declined googles inbuilt locationrequest. I have since removed this feature and my fetch statement now returns the correct data.